# How to download a DLL assembly in VB.Net if it can't be loaded

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to download a *.dll and subsequently load it if it can't be found on the local machine? I am using VB.Net and I can catch the AssemblyResolve event, but I get an exception when I try to use System.Net.WebClient to download the assembly from my web server then load it with Reflection.

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf downloadAssembly

Private Function downloadAssembly()
Dim downloader As New System.Net.WebClient()
downloader.DownloadFile(New Uri("http://path.toserver.com/myassembly.dll"), "myassembly.dll")
Dim NewAssembly As Reflection.Assembly
NewAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("myassembly.dll")
Return NewAssembly
End Function
```

```
The exception is of type: System.InvalidOperationException
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: wind-x.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4f5104ea
  Problem Signature 04: Wind-X
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4f5104ea
  Problem Signature 07: 1f
  Problem Signature 08: c6
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: What exception do you get, and on what line? If possible, please post the stacktrace from the exception as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Fredrik. I've added the error information it throws to me.

Comment: Is a full path to myassembly.dll required? Maybe this page is useful? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Answer (score 0):

*I know that this i a very old question, but the problem is still interesting for me and probably others.*

I just tried your code and it works for me. You are not very clear where you add the handler. I tried to add an application event like this:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
  AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf Form1.downloadAssembly
End Sub
```

Since your exception message isn't very clear to me, try adding the following application event handling for uncaught exceptions (or add an appropriate try/catch for you assembly loading):

```
Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
  MsgBox(e.Exception.Message)
End Sub
```

I looked up the documentation for the Uri-contstructor, WebClient.DownloadFile and Assembly.LoadFrom. If I haven't missed anything none of these methods raise the InvalidOperationException. So I can only guess very wildly what you could try:

1. Try a different assembly to make sure, it's not the assembly itself, that's causing the problem. I could imagine that a mismatch in the assemblies framework and the applications framework version could cause some trouble.
2. Try to start the application from a folder, that has maximum privileges set to rule out any problems related to user rights. If that works, you probably need user elevation.
3. If all of that doesn't give you a clue, try to make a minimum example with as few code in your application and your assembly as possible.